# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch-SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [/MusicStore]

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

when I remove the line "ModelAttribute (" OrderDetail ") List  OrderDetail" does not show up any more errors. but if I put the line "List  OrderDetail = new ArrayList  ();" when i load again it will lose data in the list. anyone can help me?

Cartcontroller.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"addcart.html"})
    public String addCart(@RequestParam(value = "albumId") int albumId,
            @ModelAttribute("orderDetail") ModelMap model, @ModelAttribute("orderDetail") List<OrderDetail> orderDetail ) {
        if (orderDetail.size() == 0) {
            Album album = albumService.findAlbum(albumId);
            OrderDetail ordetail = new OrderDetail(album, 1);
            orderDetail.add(ordetail);
        } else {
            boolean isDup = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < orderDetail.size(); i++) {
                if (orderDetail.get(i).getAlbum().getAlbumId() == albumId) {
                    int quantity = orderDetail.get(i).getQuantity();
                    orderDetail.get(i).setQuantity(quantity + 1);
                    isDup = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (isDup == false) {
                Album album = albumService.findAlbum(albumId);
                OrderDetail ordetail = new OrderDetail(album, 1);
                orderDetail.add(ordetail);
            }
        }
        List<Album> albumList = albumService.getAllAlbums();
        model.addAttribute("albumList", albumList);
        model.addAttribute("sumTypeOrder", orderDetail.size());
        return "home";
    }
```

home.jsp

```
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('User')">
                <div id="logtab">
                    <spring:message code="user.logged" />
                    :
                    <sec:authentication property="name" />
                </div>
            </sec:authorize>
            <div id="logtab">
                <c:if test="${sumTypeOrder}>0">
                    <a href="cart">Your Cart("${sumTypeOrder}")</a>
                </c:if>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="content">
            <c:forEach items="${albumList}" var="album">
                <div class="album">
                    <td align="center">${album.name}</td>
                    <td align="center">${album.singer}</td>
                    <td align="center">${album.releaseDate}</td>
                    <td><a href="addcart.html?albumId=${album.albumId}">Add
                            to cart</a></td>
                </div>
            </c:forEach>
        </div>
        <div class="right"></div>
        <div class="footer"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

loginController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/home", "/" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String welcomePage(Model model, Map<String, Object> map) {
        model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        model.addAttribute("album", new Album());
        Album album = new Album();
        map.put("album", album);
        map.put("albumList", albumService.getAllAlbums());
        return "home";
    }
```

exception:

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path
>   [/MusicStore] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested
>   exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type
>   mismatch] with root cause java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument
>   type mismatch     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:436)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:424)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:900)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: you are not setting value of modelAttribute orderDetail on your jsp page

Comment: Why do you have 2 parameters with `@ModelAttribute` which point to the same attribute??? Also you cannot have a list as backing object you have to wrap it in an object.